# как узнать время которое участник провёл на сервере через бота на python

Tags: python, бот

намутил сервер дискорд, за ним и бота написал, решил сделать так чтобы роли выдавались по времени проведённому на сервере, с ролями разобрался, а вот по времени вопрос, подскажите люди добрые

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант - запускать таймер, когда пользователь входит на сервер.

```py
import asyncio

...

roles = {
   0: 'newbie', # выдаётся сразу при входе
   600: 'member', # выдаётся через 10 минут (600 секунд)
   3000: 'advanced', # выдаётся через час (3 600 секунд, 600 уже за счёт прошлой роли)
   82800: 'staff', # выдаётся через день (86 400 секунд)
   518400: 'moder' # выдаётся через неделю (604 800 секунд)
}

@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    for key in roles:
        await asyncio.sleep(key)
        await member.add_roles(discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name = roles[key]))
```

Не советую использовать на долгосрочную перспективу. Если роль нужно выдавать через месяц после входа на сервер, от этой реализации лучше отказаться. В таком случае лучше раз в определённый промежуток времени сравнивать дату входа пользователя с текущей датой. Выдаваться роль будет не сразу (в зависимости от того, как часто будет делаться проверка), но это будет более эффективно

Узнать, когда пользователь вошёл на сервер можно с помощью атрибута `joined_at` (`member.joined_at`), который возвращает дату/время входа на сервер типа `datetime.datetime`. А точная реализация выдачи ролей этим методом уже зависит от того, как вы будете организовывать проверку.